# Как одним зопросом вывести и имя категории и новости данной категории

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте у меня такой вопрос как одним запросом можно вывести на экран

```
Катагория 1
    Новость 3
    Новость 34
Категория 2
    Новость 5
    Новость 43
```

База

```
news
   id       cid       name
    1         1          Новость 3
    2         1          Новость 34
    3         2          Новость 5
    4         2          Новость 43

category
   id       name
    1          Катагория 1
    2          Катагория 2
```

Ну с запросом тут всё понятно конечно но как вывести это на экран как на верхнем примере используя только 1 запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("select category.name, news.name from news inner join category on news.cid=category.id");

$cat="";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
          if($cat != $row['0']) {
                if($cat != "") echo "</ul>";
                $cat=$row['0'];
                echo "<ul>".$row['0'];
            }
    echo "<ul>".$row['1']."</ul>";
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

Если возможны категории без новостей, то:

```
$result = mysql_query("select category.name, news.name from news right outer join category on news.cid=category.id");
```

и

```
if(!is_null($row['1'])) echo "<ul>".$row['1']."</ul>";
```

Comment: Извените но это ни так как на примере имя категории не должно повторяться

Comment: А  оно у вас повторяется? Результат можно увидеть?

     <ul>Категория 1<ul>Новость 3</ul><ul>Новость 34</ul></ul> 
     <ul>Категория 2<ul>Новость 5</ul><ul>Новость 43</ul></ul>

Comment: извените @alexlz да всё правильно я не правильно создал базу исправил всё правильно спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
select category.name, news.name from news inner join category on news.cid=category.id
```

Comment: @shurik c запросом так и так всё понятно а как это вывести как на примере?